# Node.js app to keep track of dynamic IP Address of dell edge box?

Tags: ip-address

I have dell edge box that is stored in another location, the edge box is having 4G sim card internet access with dynamic IP address that changes frequently, I usually use ssh putty with the 4G IP address which is IPv6, now if the IP address changes i will not be able to know the updated ip address of the edge box, any ideas how can  I keep track of the ip address with a microservice using node.js.
Thakns in advance.
Seham.

Comment: There's roughly a gazillion softwares to do this already. No one needs a new one in node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edge box will have to tell you its new address whenever the address changes. I.e. don't treat it as a server that you connect to, instead let it connect somewhere else. For example, the edge box could connect to a VPN so that you can assign it a stable logical IP address within your VPN even though the VPN connection is tunnelled through changing connections.

This is a networking problem, not a microservice or NodeJs problem. Even though VPNs are getting better, any such solution is still quite fragile. Carefully evaluate whether having to connect to a machine without a stable IP address is really the best solution for your requirements. Also consider whether your network operator would be able to assign a stable IP to the device as part of their business offerings.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply